# Link records to others

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with commissions for example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWgTe.png

And second table with relations between them: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3472.png

How to link all commissions which commission_number ends with "/1" to other with the same number?

Example:

`222/2021/1 (parent)` link to `222/2021/2`, `222/2021/3`, `222/2021/4`... `(child)`.
Can I link all commissions to his parents with one procedure?

Comment: Can you explain what you want exactly ? Post table description, sample datas and the result you want as we can help you.

Comment: I need a link commissions that end with "/ 1" with commissions that are their children, for example: 1/2021/1 link to 1/2021/2, 1/2021/3. The database is too big to do it manually and I need a procedure that will link all parents with their children.

Comment: parent's number - 1/2021/1

children's number - 1/2021/2, 1/2021/3 ...

Comment: You want to fill the table `commision_relation` with that datas ? you want to add a column to the table `commissions` and fill it ?

Comment: I want to fill the table 'commission_relation'

Comment: Why don't you add a column parent_id in commission table ? It would be easier to maintain as long as one child has only one parent.

Comment: I cannot do this because the system is designed to have a separate table

Comment: When you're asking for help, please don't post screenshots or photographs. Cut & paste the text into the reddit message.

Why?
1. It's easier for people to read it.
2. It allows those reading it to cut & paste the text, making it easier to work on solving your problem.
3. It makes it searchable, so that someone can find this thread when Googling for information in the future.
4. A screen reader can't read a picture which limits access to some in our community.

Answer (score 0):

You could construct the parent number by replacing the suffix with "1" and aggregate.  The following gives a list of all related commission numbers:

```
select regexp_replace(commission_number, '[0-9]+$', '1') as parent_commission_number,
       array_agg(commission_number)
from t
group by parent_commission_number;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that

```
insert into commission_to_commission(child_commission_id,parent_commission_id)
select c_child.commission_id,c_parent.commission_id
from commission c_child, commission c_parent
where c_parent.commission_number = left(c_child.commission_number,9) || '1'
and right(c_child.commission_number,2) <> '/1';
```

See example here [Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/joBW9RqBCnigKsxEkkGXfZ/1)